# ASP.NET and OpenXML - Create formatted/styled xlsx file - Best Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net, openxml, xlsx

This question might be more subjective, but I'm hoping someone with more experience can guide me in the right direction.

I'm brand new to web development, but have been coding C# for a couple years. My job wants me to convert an existing app we have to SharePoint 2013 and part of the app generates an excel report with custom formats and styling. In the original app we used Interop, but apparently since it's 32bit and our server is 64bit, Interop won't work. I thought about just doing a csv, but our customer is adamant about keeping the styling so I found OpenXML.

I don't have any experience with OpenXML, but I saw the tool can convert files into code. I loaded our template into the tool and it generated about 2000 lines of code which seems very excessive. Using Interop it's a fraction of the length and seems much easier to read. I'm tempted to just copy all the code over and stick it in a region (which I know most developers hate and I agree looks bad) and put a note at the top saying that if the template ever changes to just redo that region with the new one.

Is that my best option or is there a better alternative? Unfortunately our dev network is pretty closed off (it's a pain to get approval on third party non Microsoft stuff) so I'm limited on third party libraries I can add as well. If there's an option without doing that, that'd be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

If you have one or more templates, just use OpenXML to create a new workbook from a template for each request. And then use code to enter values into named ranges, datasets into rows, etc.

BTW—ClosedXML makes simple and medium things a lot easier.

Comment: It's 2 templates total and that was my plan to add the info. I'm more asking if it's bad practice to just copy over the code the tool creates and stick them in a region since they're so long. Also, I saw ClosedXML and it looked like it would make things easier, but I doubt my work would approve it unfortunately.

Comment: You could put the generated code into a method and put the method into a separate file of a partial class. Configure any code inspection tools to skip the file as generated code.